# How do I draw a process tree from my shell to the kernel?

Tags: process

I can't understand this problem

For each
process in the tree, indicate the name of the process, the process's
ID number, and the name of the owner of the process.

Comment: If this is some kind of [tag:homework], which it certainly looks like, you should tag it with appropriate tag.

Comment: And what do you not understand? How to start xterm?

Comment: I don't understand from " draw a tree of processes..." which processes is it talking about? Just starting a bash shell?

Comment: The following command should somehow do the same as you described: `ps axjf | awk '{ $1=$3=$4=$5=$6=$7=$9=""; print $0 }'`

Comment: In fact, my command doesn't show the names of the owners of the processes, it just shows their UID's. And notice that my command is just very fast workaround for this.

Comment: do you know `pstree` -> http://www.linfo.org/pstree.html

Answer (score 3):

> For each process in the tree, indicate the name of the process, the , and the name of the owner of the process.

You need a way to get this information, probably based on PID (the "process's ID number"), since the PPID (parent process id) will lead you up the tree to the parent process.  Clue: the PID of the current bash process is in `$BASHPID` (or `$$`).

> Draw the tree of processes and parent processes starting from your shell and going all the way up to the kernel

Clue #2: The kernel only ever starts one process, the init daemon (traditionally called `init`, but it may be called something else).  That process's PID is 1, and its parent process is 0.  Everything else is a descendant of init, so that's where your tree leads.

Technically, I don't think what you are being asked to do is draw a *tree*, you're being asked to draw a *chain*, although conceptually that chain is a path through a tree (think of a file *path*, which is a series/chain of directories that are part of a larger directory tree).  You are tracing back up through the branches of that conceptual tree to the "root" of the tree (trees in computer science are usually represented upside down compared to a real tree, with the base/root at the top and the branches branching downward).

```
          root
         /    \
        /\    /\
       /\/\  /\/\
```

Comment: `$$` is POSIX to get the shell's PID, no need to use a bashism.

Comment: @Mat Right-o. Not to be confused with `$?`!

Comment: Or `$!` indeed (which is also quite useful itself).

Comment: btw starting a bash shell in xterm means just to start new xterm as background process right? also "starting from your shell" means which shell, the new one that I opened or the original one? thank you

Comment: Starting an xterm starts a shell inside of it; I guess it doesn't matter *how* you start the xterm.  In this case, the new shell's parent process will be the xterm.  Look at `ps -lp $$`.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a job for `pstree`:

`pstree -npu`

- **`pstree`** → display the processes in a tree format, starting (correctly) from `init`
- **`-n`** → sort by PID (Process ID) instead alphabetically
- **`-u`** → displays owner (user who stared it)
- (extra: **`-h`** highlights the current process and its ancestors)

The full manual for more options can be found here → http://www.linfo.org/pstree.html or locally in the `man`/`info` page of your trust: `man 1 pstree`